# Creating new docker-compose for testing with new volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, volumes

I have `dev-docker-compose.yml` with several backends and several databases like `postgres`, `redis` etc...
Now I want to create `test-docker-compose.yml` with changed name for the services 
For example I had:

```
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

and now i have changed it to

```
  test_postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - test_postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

But when I connect to it with `navicat` or `dbeaver` I see the same values that was in first variant.

Can somebody explain me why this behavior exist and how to solve it?

Comment: Did you run `docker-compose down` bevor?

Comment: Have you tried using a different volume path for the test DB?

Comment: @YaronIdan can you provide which path, depending on what i provide, ?

Comment: @Wie if i do docker-compose down - will i lose all the data from databases?

Comment: @illdo Just try changing the last line in your docker-compose.yaml from `- test_postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data` to `- test_postgres:/var/lib/test_postgresql/data`

Comment: @Yaron Idan Dear, are you sure? because `/var/lib/postgresql/data` its required by postgresql container setup, its defaul location of postgresql data. When i do new container- anyway that value should be another ( in new container)- new volume

Comment: I see what you're saying but I just think you should rule out the possibility that docker is reusing the volume between both containers.

Comment: Have you check docker service and container of service, is it running ur new `test-docker-compose.yml` ? Did you `docker-compose down` for your old service and `docker-compose up` for you new service?

Comment: @vengleabso , dude ii do `down ` i ll lose data - i can not do down. because i need the data. Please understand it

Comment: `down` does not remove volumes, unless you explicitly specify the `-v` flag, so your data should be fine.
However - if the data you have on the volume is important, saving it in an anonymous volume seems very risky anyway.

Comment: @YaronIdan is right, you should not loose data. And your volumes are named. If you do only `docker-compose up` your service will refresh with the same properties. Did you run `docker-compose -f path/to/your/file.yaml up`?